# How does an object in vacuum loose its temperature?

Tags: photons, temperature, radiation

Well, it radiates in the infrared, I guess. But how exactly are these photons created? The atoms have some kinetic energy, which makes up the temperature. So while the atoms or molecules jitter a bit relative to each other, how does this spontaneously create a photon?

Comment: Hi Harald. Objects in a vacuum radiate by [black body radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation).

Answer (score 0):

The electrons are also jittering, and because these are charged particles they will emit light when accelerating. For example electrons will have certain rotational and vibrational modes of oscillation.